# Regexp, greediness until second match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying something like this

```
^(.*)[\s]*(?:\[[\s]*(.*)[\s]*\])?$
```

My idea is that first match returns everything but the occasional second match which is anything inside []. Incoming string to match is already trimmed.

For instance

```
'aaaaa [] [ddd]' -> returns 'aaaa []' plus 'ddd'
'[] [ddd]' -> returns '[]' plus 'ddd'
'aaaaaaaa' -> returns 'aaaaaaa' plus NULL
'aaaaaaaa []' -> returns 'aaaaaaa' plus ''
'aaaaaa [' -> returns 'aaaaaa [' plus NULL
'aaaa [] ddd' -> returns 'aaaa [] ddd' plus NULL
'[a] [b] [c] [d]' returns '[a] [b] [c]' plus 'd' instead of '' plus 'a] [b] [c] [d' 
'[fff]' -> return '' plus 'fff' <- That's particular since first match can never be null
```

My main problems are due to the first match, since both .* (swallows all) and *? (swallows only until first ] if multiple) give an undesired result

Pseudocode for algorithm would be something like:

- If last char is a ']', second match will be anything inside up to the
  closest '[' backwards (if exist) -> this can be null or '' if input
  string ends with '[]'
- Rest is first match, which cannot be NULL, only
  ''

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can the "second match which is anything inside []" include other square brackets?

Comment: Does it mean 'a [] [] [] [] [asd]' should give just 'a [] [] [] []' and 'asd'?

Comment: @user1352530 if it can, then I think using regex here is not a good idea (since undefined nested level is a problem in regex - not unsolvable, of cause)

Comment: Affirmative to the first question, and wondering a rationale for the second

Comment: So it's also acceptable for the first match to return `aaaaa` plus `] [ddd`? (looking at the outer set of `[` `]`)

Comment: No, it should'nt. I updated with more cases (now I understand what you meant by "anything insde square brackets")

Comment: I appended the pseudoalgorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no nesting, you can use this regex:

```
^(.*?)\s*(?:\[([^\]]*)\])?$
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/pH7tD6)

Otherwise, if you can have nested `[]` in the main `[]`, then the regex will have to be revised. You can make a regex for nested `[]` but only up to a certain level of nesting; if you have up to 2 levels of nesting, you make a regex for 2, if you have up to 5 levels of nesting, you make a more complex one for 5, etc.

Comment: It seems that in square brackets can be nested brackets and even bad-ordered (something like `aaaaa [] [dd[foo[] bar ][d]`)

Comment: Thanks! But this solution does not match when I input '[abc]', it should return '' plus 'abc'

Comment: @user1352530 Are you 100% sure about that?

Comment: Thanks! I copied exactly you regex and inputed some things in scriptular site. Unless it is badly designed, yes I think so

Comment: @user1352530 it's working for me; here's a fiddle for `[fff]`: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rYqUK/).

Comment: uhmmm. You are right... Scriptular seems broken or I am doing something wrong. I'll test it better with different strings and check your answer if it works in all cases! Thanks!

Comment: @user1352530 Okay! Word of warning again though, it won't be working for nested `[]`. If you know you have some threshold level of nesting of `[]` however, there might be something that can be done :)

Comment: It'sp erfect. I only added the [\s]* at the end of the first match for trimming and it works flawless. Thank you!!

Comment: @user1352530 Oh right! I should probably add it as well. By the way, you don't need to wrap it around square brackets; `\s*` has the same behaviour :)

Comment: Thank you and sorry... I saw what you said about nesting (I should have included an example abovwe), '[4]]' matches it in the first group instead of the second! Anyway it's so far the best answer and if noone finds a better solution in a day or two I'll give it to you anyway because it is almost perfect

Comment: @user1352530 That one's really broken on the square brackets xD I'm not sure how you can work with such data, but that one's worse than nesting!

Comment: Yes, Indeed there is a minimal chance of that occurring, but I have to be aware of any inputted thing in this God's land xD

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do but, here is a try : `/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]$/`.

Another try, allowing the second group to remain undefined : `/(.*?)(?:\[(.*?)\])?$/`.

I have never used Scriptular but here is what Chrome's console says :

```
// result : [full match, group 1, group 2]
'abc'.match(/(.*?)(?:\[(.*?)\])?$/) // ["abc", "abc", undefined]
'[abc]'.match(/(.*?)(?:\[(.*?)\])?$/) // ["[abc]", "", "abc"]
```

What about this one : `/(.*?)(?:\[([^\[]*?)\])?$/`?

```
'aze[[[rty]'.match(/(.*?)(?:\[([^\[]*?)\])?$/) // ["aze[[[rty]", "aze[[", "rty"]
```

Last try : `/(.+?)(?:\[([^\[]*?)\])?$/`.

```
test         result
-------------------------------------------
''           null
'aze'        ["aze", "aze", undefined]
'[rty]'      ["[rty]", "[rty]", undefined]
'aze[rty]'   ["aze[rty]", "aze", "rty"]
'aze[]'      ["aze[]", "aze", ""]
'aze[][rty]' ["aze[][rty]", "aze[]", "rty"]
'aze[[]rty]' ["aze[[]rty]", "aze[", "]rty"]
```

Comment: Thank you, algorithm is appended to my original post. This solution does not work for me, as 'abc','[abc]', are not matched among others. Perhaps scriptular is bad programmed?

Comment: @user1352530 The last one seems to be quite close to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think regular expressions are not the answer here, especially because you give a simple algorithm to solve the problem. Just translate your algorithm into code.

Also regular expressions are not the solution because you have unbalanced and nested [] as you state in your comments, which make regex impractical.

Try some javascript like this :

```
function parse ( text ) {
    var first, inside;
    if ( text.substr (-1) == ']' ) {
        var pos = text.lastIndexOf ('[');
        first = text.substr (0, pos);
        inside = text.substr ( pos + 1, text.length -pos - 1);
    } else {
        first = text;
     }
     return [ first, inside ];
}
```

Comment: I'll check this code for errors later, when I have access to a PC.

Comment: Useful! I am really doubting between letting wrong (but exceptional input) tih the nicer regex for the past answer or doing this